# How to make tasks in Discord.py 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I updated my discord bot to dis.py 2.0 and im getting this error only since i updated to discord.py 2.0 heres my code

code:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix,
                   help_command=None,
                   intents=discord.Intents.all())

@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def checkforvideos():
  # Checks for new yt videos

checkforvideos.start()
def run():
 
    bot.loop.create_task(checkforvideos())

    server.run()
    for extension in bot.initial_extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension)
    bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"), bot=True, reconnect=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 339, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': run()
  File "main.py", line 319, in run
    checkforvideos.start()
  File "/home/runner/bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 400, in start
    self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._loop(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 381, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
```

This worked on 1.7.3 of discord.py and i have no ideas whats wrong i even tried example from the docs and those didn't work if you guys could help me that would be great!

Comment: Can you add the entire code to the question, specifically where you instantiate the client and start it?

Comment: Sure I'll edit it right now.

Comment: I believe loading extensions is async now. You probably need to use `start` in a coroutine and then use `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())` - but with `main` being async function.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really dumb since 2.0 could you give a example?

Comment: `async def main():`; `task.start()`; `await client.start('token')`; then run that from asyncio. You also need `await bot.load_extension` I believe.